# Symlinked plugin directory doesn't appear in Admin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a simple test plugin - a folder called `tester` containing a file called `tester.php` that contains only this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My tester
*/
?>
```

I have a copy of WordPress running locally on my Mac. When the plugin is in the plugins directory it appears in the Admin list of plugins.

When I move the plugin directory elsewhere and symlink to it, it doesn't show up.

I've done similar with a theme, and WordPress happily uses that. From what I've read this should now work with plugins too. Am I missing something?

(WordPress 4.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have you done to add the symlink?

In using VVV I am able to symlink using your plugin tester code:

```
    # ssh into vagrant
    $ vagrant ssh
    # create symlink
    $ sudo ln -s /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/testing-dir/tester /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/tester
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of making the symlink from within Vagrant! Doing that (in my case `sudo ln -s /var/www/tester /var/www/public/wp/wp-content/plugins/tester`) seems to work, thanks! It's odd that I could make a symlink for a theme on my Mac, not in Vagrant.

Comment: Also ensure WordPress has access to the linked folder. In my case on Windows it was the reason why it wasn't working

Comment: How can you achieve the same with docker?